# OSX Flash CS5 keyboard shortcut for next window/tab?

Tags: macos, flash, adobe-cs5

Is there any way to change windows and tabs with a keyboard shortcut in Flash CS5 on Mac OS X?

Comment: I'm having the same problem on the Mac.  Argh... quite frustrating.  Surely there must be a shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha, found it.

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> to cycle forwards.

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> to cycle backwards.

Comment: Nice one Simon! I couldn't find that anywhere in the docs or menu Shortcuts area :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> should work for moving to the next tab, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> for moving to the previous tab.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gareth but is that Windows only? Can't get it to work on OSX!

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear from your question if you were using Windows or Mac OS X. How about ⌘ + Tab on your Mac?

Comment: Hi Gareth no that's the OS app switcher. I updated question title to be clearer. Your score is currently 1337, LEET!